# Hazard Ratio Curve - SAS

Tags: sas, cox-regression

Can someone please tell me, which SAS procedure to use or any other method in SAS to draw a Hazard Ratio Curve as shown in the link below:

http://figshare.com/articles/_Hazard_ratio_curves_for_the_association_between_NT_proBNP_levels_and_the_risk_of_heart_failure_in_non_obese_n_8202_8202_1_095_and_obese_n_8202_8202_265_participants_/1251609

Because, i don't know yet how to retain the Hazard Ratio values that appear in the output..

Thank you..

Comment: I could be wrong but I don't think that output will come directly from a procedure; it will have to be constructed by capturing procedure output and plotting using `sgplot` or a similar procedure.

Comment: Proc Phreg can get you close, but the notes indicate a cubic spline cox regression and I'm not sure how you'd do that in SAS.